# BigCommerce's Stencil CLI and port selection

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

When running `stencil start` you'll get some information such as

```
-------------------------------------------------

[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:3001
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://147.182.158.57:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://localhost:3002
 ---------------------------------------
```

I know that I can specify the Local/External port in the `config.stencil.json` file. However, I don't seem to have any control on the proxying and UI ports which leads to collisions.

Is there a way to specify these? I'd even settle for disabling browsersync and the UI stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the default start port using

```
stencil init … —port xxxx
```

However it doesn’t seem like you can change the proxy port.

Reference: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/stencil-cli-options-and-commands#stencil-init